# How to count cell changes of 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to improve a shared excel file , to be able to show the times a specific cell is changed.

However, I do not know how to code

I would like to put a code that counts the times two other cells in that row are changed and sum them up in a cell for the whole column range.

For example, count how many times column U and Z is changed (I have a drop-down on both with 3 options "OK,Change,TBC") and sum up these changes in cell X.

Specifically, if someone changes a cell in column U and another user makes a change in cell Z or U (of that same row), that column X will have 2 as value number 2 and so on.

Really appreciate your time.

Comment: *However, I do not know how to code* - we don't code for you, but are happy to help with existing code that is *not* working. If you don't know how to code VBA, there's plenty of tutorials online where you can get help.

Comment: *the following code* - there's no code, but edit your original question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score -2):

Well I have used the following code but it seems to work only for 1 cell. I would like to include 2 columns where it checks and paste the count on another cell.

```
Dim xCount As Integer

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    If Target = Range("U6") Then
        xCount = xCount + 1
        Range("X6").Value = xCount                                    
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set xRg = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, Me.Range("U6"))
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then
        xCount = xCount + 1
        Range("X6").Value = xCount
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You must remove `On Error Resume Next` and fix your errors. This is a very bad practice and just hides **all** error messages in the whole code. But the errors still occur. Instead make your code stable and fix the errors or implement a complete error handling! You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling). Also your `EnableEvents = False` does not cover the first `Range("X6").Value = xCount` but it has to (otherwise you will trigger the event again over and over).